# Interface extending a class

Tags: java

Let's say that I have an interface, and all classes that implement that interface also extend a certain super class.

```
public class SuperClass {
    public void someMethod() {...}
}

public interface MyInterface {
    void someOtherMethod();
}

//many (but not all) sub classes do this
public class SubClass extends SuperClass implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void someOtherMethod() {...}
}
```

Then if I'm dealing with an object of type `MyInterface` and I don't know the specific sub class, I have to hold two references to the same object:

```
MyInterface someObject = ...;
SuperClass someObjectCopy = (SuperClass) someObject; //will never throw ClassCastException
someObjectCopy.someMethod();
someObject.someOtherMethod();
```

I tried making the interface extend the super class, but it's a compiler error:

```
public interface MyInterface extends SuperClass {} //compiler error
```

I also thought of combining the interface and the super class into an abstract class like so:

```
public abstract class NewSuperClass {
    public void someMethod();
    public abstract void someOtherMethod();
}
```

But then i can't have a sub class that doesn't want to implement `someOtherMethod()`.
So is there a way to signify that every class that implements an interface also extends a certain class, or do I have no choice but to carry around two references to the same object?

Comment: You could have a method `public SuperClassType getAsSuperClassType()`. The real question is: why do you need to have the reference to the super class? It indicates some kind of faulty design.

Comment: You are confused. Do you want all classes to implement both the interface and the method in class or do you want some of them to do that? I think you want the second thing. Firstly sit down and think about what you want of the two things that I mentioned.

Comment: @AseemBansal I want the second thing, because there are lots of classes that extend SuperClass, but don't implement MyInterface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the only solution you have would be to have a reference to both, but this indicates that you have a design flaw somewhere. The reason I say is because you should think of an `interface` as something that your implementing classes will always need. For example, a Car and Airplane both need a Drive() interface. A design reconsideration is probably worth your time. However, if you still want to follow that path, you can do the following:

```
public class ClassA {
   public void methodA(){};
}
public abstract class ClassB extends Class A{
   public void methodB();    
}
```

After you have the above setup, you can now reference an object that has the two methods by doing the following:

```
ClassB classB = new ClassB();
classB.methodA();
classB.methodB();
```

Now you don't actually have to actually use two pointers to the same object.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I have multiple interfaces in the same situation. So if I made them all into multiple abstract classes, the sub class couldn't extend them all. I'm looking into a design reconsideration now. Thanks!

Comment: How on earth are you instantiating an abstract class?